# LibVLC always goes to "eventHardwareAccelerationError"

Tags: android, libvlc

When I play an rtsp on VLC player, I can get the rtsp. But when I use the android application I created using LibVLC, I always get to this part

```
public void eventHardwareAccelerationError() {
        Log.e(TAG, "eventHardwareAccelerationError()!");
        return;
    }
```

and it doesn't show anything on the screen. I tested a different URL such as `http://clips.corwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4`, I don't get any problem. The address I am trying to connect is:

```
rtsp://mysername:mypassword@192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif
```

Please see my log below:

```
2022-04-21 08:34:13.058 10597-10597/? I/vlcplayersampl: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2022-04-21 08:34:13.076 10597-10597/? W/vlcplayersampl: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2022-04-21 08:34:13.213 10597-10597/? I/vlcplayersampl: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2022-04-21 08:34:13.392 10597-10597/? W/vlcplayersampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2022-04-21 08:34:13.392 10597-10597/? W/vlcplayersampl: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2022-04-21 08:34:13.514 10597-10597/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2022-04-21 08:34:13.564 10597-10616/? D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe35a3280, tid 10616
2022-04-21 08:34:13.566 10597-10616/? D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
2022-04-21 08:34:13.577 10597-10616/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2022-04-21 08:34:13.577 10597-10616/? I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2022-04-21 08:34:13.577 10597-10616/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2022-04-21 08:34:13.578 10597-10616/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2022-04-21 08:34:13.578 10597-10616/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2022-04-21 08:34:13.578 10597-10616/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2022-04-21 08:34:13.590 10597-10616/? D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2022-04-21 08:34:13.591 10597-10616/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe35852a0: maj 3 min 1 rcv 4
2022-04-21 08:34:13.616 10597-10616/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe35852a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3583690)
2022-04-21 08:34:13.618 10597-10616/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2022-04-21 08:34:13.618 10597-10616/? E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
2022-04-21 08:34:13.641 10597-10616/? D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2022-04-21 08:34:13.641 10597-10616/? D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe35a35a0, tid 10616
2022-04-21 08:34:13.643 10597-10616/? D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_sync_buffer_data GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_1 
2022-04-21 08:34:13.643 10597-10616/? E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2022-04-21 08:34:13.695 10597-10616/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe35852a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3583690)
2022-04-21 08:34:13.699 10597-10616/? D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 2
2022-04-21 08:34:13.753 10597-10597/? I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2560 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
2022-04-21 08:34:16.277 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@4dd6a83
2022-04-21 08:34:16.284 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VideoVLCActivity: VideoVLC -- onCreate -- START ------------
2022-04-21 08:34:16.301 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample W/VLC/LibVLC: Unable to load the anw library: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libhardware.so" not found
2022-04-21 08:34:16.302 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample W/linker: Warning: "/data/app/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample-gElr48IPo_W6N4BGvr2XAg==/lib/x86/libvlcjni.so" has text relocations and will not work when the app moves to API level 23 or later (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/Text-Relocations-Enforced-for-API-level-23) (allowing for now because this app's target API level is still 22)
2022-04-21 08:34:16.342 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC/JNI/main: JNI interface loaded.
2022-04-21 08:34:16.344 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC/LibVLC: HWDec enabled: device working with: mediacodec,iomx,all
2022-04-21 08:34:16.344 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample V/VLC/LibVLC: Initializing LibVLC
2022-04-21 08:34:16.345 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample I/VLC/LibVLC/Util: ELF ABI = x86, 32bits
2022-04-21 08:34:16.345 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample I/VLC/LibVLC/Util: ELF arch = null
2022-04-21 08:34:16.345 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample I/VLC/LibVLC/Util: ELF fpu = false
2022-04-21 08:34:16.353 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample W/VLC/LibVLC/Util: Could not find maximum CPU frequency!
2022-04-21 08:34:16.354 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC/LibVLC: Used bogoMIPS due to lack of frequency info
2022-04-21 08:34:16.354 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC/JNI/main: Using deblocking level 1
2022-04-21 08:34:16.354 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC/JNI/main: Chroma set to ""
2022-04-21 08:34:16.354 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC/JNI/main: Subtitle encoding set to ""
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: VLC media player - 3.0.0-git Vetinari
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: Copyright © 1996-2015 the VideoLAN team
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: revision 2.2.0-git-3062-g3add837
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: configured with ../configure  '--host=i686-linux-android' '--build=x86_64-unknown-linux' '--disable-nls' '--enable-live555' '--enable-realrtsp' '--enable-avformat' '--enable-swscale' '--enable-avcodec' '--enable-opus' '--enable-opensles' '--enable-android-surface' '--enable-mkv' '--enable-taglib' '--enable-dvbpsi' '--disable-vlc' '--disable-shared' '--disable-update-check' '--disable-vlm' '--disable-dbus' '--disable-lua' '--disable-vcd' '--disable-v4l2' '--disable-gnomevfs' '--enable-dvdread' '--enable-dvdnav' '--disable-bluray' '--disable-linsys' '--disable-decklink' '--disable-libva' '--disable-dv1394' '--enable-mod' '--disable-sid' '--disable-gme' '--disable-tremor' '--enable-mad' '--disable-dca' '--disable-sdl-image' '--enable-zvbi' '--disable-fluidsynth' '--disable-jack' '--disable-pulse' '--disable-alsa' '--disable-samplerate' '--disable-sdl' '--disable-xcb' '--disable-atmo' '--disable-qt' '--disable-skins2' '--disable-mtp' '--disable-notify' '--enable-libass' '--disable-svg' '-
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: plug-ins loaded: 253 modules
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e982bd94] core logger: looking for logger module matching "any": 4 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e982bd94] core logger: using logger module "android_logger"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.360 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: translation test: code is "C"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.361 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cea03434] core libvlc: CPU has capabilities MMX MMXEXT SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 FPU 
2022-04-21 08:34:16.361 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample I/VLC/JNI/main: LibVLC initialized: 0xcea540e0
2022-04-21 08:34:16.362 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1b89804] core generic: creating audio output
2022-04-21 08:34:16.362 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1b96fb4] core audio output: looking for audio output module matching "android_audiotrack": 4 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.362 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1b96fb4] core audio output: using audio output module "android_audiotrack"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.362 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1b89804] core generic: keeping audio output
2022-04-21 08:34:16.362 10597-10597/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: Creating an input for 'rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.363 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB, in path '/tmp'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.363 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: `rtsp://mysername:mypassword@192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.363 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: specified demux `any'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.363 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: creating demux: access='rtsp' demux='any' location='rtsp://mysername:mypassword@192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif' file='(null)'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.363 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] core demux: looking for access_demux module matching "rtsp": 6 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.363 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: version 2014.07.25
2022-04-21 08:34:16.364 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Opening connection to 172.29.121.44, port 554...
2022-04-21 08:34:16.371 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: ...remote connection opened
    Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 2
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
2022-04-21 08:34:16.395 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received 139 new bytes of response data.
    Received a complete OPTIONS response:
    RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
    CSeq: 2
    WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97"
    
    
    Resending...
2022-04-21 08:34:16.397 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Sending request: OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 3
    Authorization: Digest username="mysername", realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif", response="01446a62591fcdeb8e6a40383c1dd4a5"
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
2022-04-21 08:34:16.419 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received 158 new bytes of response data.
    Received a complete OPTIONS response:
    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
    CSeq: 3
    Server: Rtsp Server/3.0
    Public: OPTIONS, DESCRIBE, ANNOUNCE, SETUP, PLAY, RECORD, PAUSE, TEARDOWN, SET_PARAMETER, GET_PARAMETER
    
    
    Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 4
    Authorization: Digest username="mysername", realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif", response="a089713972a75e7d15cd0302ab57c571"
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
    Accept: application/sdp
2022-04-21 08:34:16.447 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received 850 new bytes of response data.
    Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
    CSeq: 4
    x-Accept-Dynamic-Rate: 1
    Content-Base: rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/
    Cache-Control: must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 610
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    
    v=0
    o=- 2259466437 2259466437 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    s=Media Server
    c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
    t=0 0
    a=control:*
    a=packetization-supported:DH
    a=rtppayload-supported:DH
    a=range:npt=now-
    m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
    a=control:trackID=0
    a=framerate:20.000000
    a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
    a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001F;sprop-parameter-sets=Z2QAH6w0yAUAW///AL0Avm4CAgKAAAH0AABOIHQwAaDgAGg4XeXGhgA0HAANBwu8uFAA,aO48MAA=
    a=recvonly
    m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 0
    a=control:trackID=1
    a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
    a=recvonly
    m=application 0 RTP/AVP 107
    a=control:trackID=4
    a=rtpmap:107 vnd.onvif.metadata/90000
    a=recvonly
2022-04-21 08:34:16.448 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: RTP subsession 'video/H264'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.448 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/trackID=0 RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 5
    Authorization: Digest username="mysername", realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/", response="1fec404cb0732d3a415ef8ae94ea008d"
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
    Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=54734-54735
2022-04-21 08:34:16.576 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received 176 new bytes of response data.
    Received a complete SETUP response:
    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
    CSeq: 5
    Session: 7537445741946;timeout=60
    Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=54734-54735;server_port=38018-38019;ssrc=0BA46D4C
    x-Dynamic-Rate: 1
2022-04-21 08:34:16.576 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: selecting program id=0
2022-04-21 08:34:16.577 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: RTP subsession 'audio/PCMU'
2022-04-21 08:34:16.578 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Sending request: SETUP rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 6
    Authorization: Digest username="mysername", realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/", response="1fec404cb0732d3a415ef8ae94ea008d"
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
    Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=58668-58669
    Session: 7537445741946
2022-04-21 08:34:16.625 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received 176 new bytes of response data.
    Received a complete SETUP
2022-04-21 08:34:16.626 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std:  response:
    RTSP/1.0 200 OK
    CSeq: 6
    Session: 7537445741946;timeout=60
    Transport: RTP/AVP/UDP;unicast;client_port=58668-58669;server_port=38020-38021;ssrc=408EC412
    x-Dynamic-Rate: 1
2022-04-21 08:34:16.626 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: setup start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
2022-04-21 08:34:16.632 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Sending request: PLAY rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/ RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 7
    Authorization: Digest username="mysername", realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/", response="8dcfabbfbdd5cd7497844afcf968abd8"
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
    Session: 7537445741946
    Range: npt=0.000-
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received 
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: 168
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std:  new bytes of response data.
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Received a complete 
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: PLAY
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std:  response:
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
    CSeq: 7
    Session: 7537445741946
    Range: npt=0.000000-
    RTP-Info: url=trackID=0;seq=17560;rtptime=826371980,url=trackID=1;seq=17592;rtptime=73503314
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: We have a timeout of 60 seconds
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: spawned timeout thread
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: play start: 0.000000 stop:0.000000
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] core demux: using access_demux module "live555"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd9034] core decoder: looking for decoder module matching "mediacodec,iomx,all": 35 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample W/VLC: [cdfd9034] mediacodec decoder: waiting for sps/pps for codec h264
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd9034] core decoder: using decoder module "mediacodec"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd93b4] core packetizer: looking for packetizer module matching "any": 22 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd93b4] h264 packetizer: found NAL_SPS (sps_id=0)
2022-04-21 08:34:16.767 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd93b4] h264 packetizer: found NAL_PPS (pps_id=0 sps_id=0)
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd93b4] core packetizer: using packetizer module "h264"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd9734] core decoder: looking for decoder module matching "mediacodec,iomx,all": 35 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd9734] g711 decoder: samplerate:8000Hz channels:1
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [cdfd9734] core decoder: using decoder module "g711"
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e3625a14] core demux meta: looking for meta reader module matching "any": 1 candidates
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e3625a14] core demux meta: no meta reader modules matched
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: `rtsp://mysername:mypassword@192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif' successfully opened
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Sending request: 
2022-04-21 08:34:16.768 10597-10630/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: GET_PARAMETER rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/ RTSP/1.0
    CSeq: 8
    Authorization: Digest username="mysername", realm="Login to 5E0033APAGA2A71", nonce="90e768529b795dc7897304a101637b97", uri="rtsp://192.168.1.1:554/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=1&unicast=true&proto=Onvif/", response="0ce09fb70c6c6172816dd3f987f0fd70"
    User-Agent: LibVLC/3.0.0-git (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.07.25)
    Session: 7537445741946
2022-04-21 08:34:16.783 10597-10616/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe35852a0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xe3583690)
2022-04-21 08:34:16.859 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1beaab4] live555 demux: tk->rtpSource->hasBeenSynchronizedUsingRTCP()
2022-04-21 08:34:16.859 10597-10631/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC: [ce9c6f14] core input: ES_OUT_RESET_PCR called
2022-04-21 08:34:16.862 10597-10634/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample D/VLC: [e1b89804] core generic: reusing audio output
```

Comment: so it works in the official app but not with your build? Which version are you building? This `eventHardwareAccelerationError` code is not part of the current code

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using my emulator which do not have a VLC player. But when I debugged it on a mobile device that has VLC player installed, it worked.